# Can't write null string in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I would like to ask if there's anything wrong. I would like to output "null" in CSV if the query didn't find any user on the Active Directory, but it is not working as expected.

Sample output:

```
Name       UserGiven   UserLastName
usvalj02adm Juhn Paul   Valencia
ustalu00    Juhn Paul   Valencia
usnaic00adm Juhn Paul   Valencia
usmenm03adm Marion Paul Mendoza
usjorv00ADM Vincent Jorge
usgols01ADM Vincent Jorge
usgedr00    Vincent Jorge
usdhaa00adm Vincent Jorge
uscrud00adm Don Eduard  Cruz
uscabg00adm Don Eduard  Cruz
```

It repeats the previous query and output it if the user is not found. Could someone help out?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users.txt' | foreach {
    $User   = Get-ADUser $_
    $Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User

    if ($User.givenName -eq $null) {
        $Empty = @{
            Name         = $_
            UserGiven    = "null"
            UserLastName = "null"
            #GroupDN      = "null"
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $Empty
    } else {
        $Props = @{
            Name         = $_
            UserGiven    = $User.givenName
            UserLastName = $User.surName
            #GroupDN      = "null"
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $Props
    }
    # One CSV line for each user/group 
} | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\UserGroups.csv' -NoTypeInfo
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't clearly understand what is your problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce. AFAICS there's nothing in the code you posted that would retain a value from a previous iteration.

Answer (score 1):

use `""` or `''` alternative of $null it's work because the string in CSV isn't null it is **""** or **''**